# asp .net 4.0 membership and mysql

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-membership

We are going to develop asp .net web application in visual studio 2010. we are using asp .net membership provider for the authentication. By default when i create project in visual studio 2010, it generates authentication code for the sql server provider and i needed to change it to MySQL provider. can anyone please guide me, is it possible to create web application by default using mysql ? if it is possible then how can it be done ?

Comment: The provider is determined in the connection string.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are starting from scratch...

The first thing you will want to do is get the latest version of [MySQL Connect](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/). This will act as the ADO.NET Driver for MySQL in your application.

Next is to configure the provider in your application configuration. IT will typically look something like this:

```
<add name="MySqlMembershipConnection"
connectionString="Data Source=server_name;user id=username;password=password
database=database_name;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

The `providerName` is what's important here. This will indicate that your provider is MySQL. The next part is the membership provider. It's type will be `MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, mysql.web`, and for the roleManager it will be `MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, mysql.web`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of providers which support this, you can read about them and choose which is best for you here:

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/dotnet/index.html#ADO.NET

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, I have done something similar but using Visual Studios 2012 Express for Web.

First in your project references include the "MySql.Data" and "MySql.Web" dll's.

After doing that you're going to need the strong name utility to get the Public Key Token from the MySql.Web.dll.

You should get something like this (the public key token is at the bottom):

---

sn of MySql.Web.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 6.6.5\Assemblies\v4.0\MySql.Web.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools>sn -Tp MySql.Web.dll

Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Strong Name Utility  Version 4.0.30319.33440
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Public key (hash algorithm: sha1):
0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100d973bda91f7175
2c78294126974a41a08643168271f65fc0fb3cd45f658da01fbca75ac74067d18e7afbf1467d7a
519ce0248b13719717281bb4ddd4ecd71a580dfe0912dfc3690b1d24c7e1975bf7eed90e4ab14e
10501eedf763bff8ac204f955c9c15c2cf4ebf6563d8320b6ea8d1ea3807623141f4b81ae30a6c
886b3ee1

Public key token is c5687fc88969c44d

---

If you right click on the dll it'll also give you the version of the dll.  The version and the public key token is needed for you to place in your web.config file.

So you're web.config file should look something like this:

```
          <membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider" >
            <providers>
              <clear/>
              <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider"
                   type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider,                 
                   MySql.Web, Version=6.6.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"

                   autogenerateschema="true"
                   connectionStringName="AdminConnString"
                   enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
                   enablePasswordReset="true"
                   requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
                   requiresUniqueEmail="false"
                   passwordFormat="Hashed"
                   maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
                   minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
                   minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
                   passwordAttemptWindow="10"
                   passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
                   applicationName="/"
                   />
            </providers>
          </membership>
```

---

Notice in the add name carrot I reference the public key token and the version of the dll.

This right there pretty much helps you link up your asp.net application to use MySQL Membership Provider.

Check out the video below, it pretty much describes what I just said:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NN4y_88vNvo

Shows how to link ASP.NET membership with MySQL.